# Unknown column in 'where not exists clause'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

There are lots of answers for "where not exists" type inserts that expect you to specify the columns to insert. I have over 400 columns, and the two tables have identical schema.

There are also lots of answers for unknown column, but not one that I can find in an insert where not exists statement. I can't understand the problem and hope someone here can help.

Here is the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70a34b/1

Here is one of several queries I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO test1 
SELECT * FROM test2 b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test2 c WHERE test1.go = c.go);
```

I get the error Unknown column 'test1.go' in 'where clause'

Comment: The problem here is test1 is not in scope as it's part of the insert, not part of the select. `INSERT INTO test1 
SELECT * FROM test2 b 
WHERE b.go not in (Select go from test1);`

Comment: @Ryan. Checking backticks was the first thing I did, and it's not the problem here. I wouldn't post the question if I hadn't already spent an hour testing it and creating the sqlfiddle.@xQbert, you're right that it's outside the scope but there are several columns that have to be matched on in order to exclude a row from the insert. How can you do this and match multiple columns. I have other queries where I specify the columns to insert and it works, but the blanket select * keeps this from working and I really don't feel like typing 408 column names into the select statement, twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip your table names around. Remember, you're trying to insert into table1 FROM table2 where the values are not already in ***TABLE1.***

Change the query to:

```
 INSERT INTO test1 
 SELECT * FROM test2 b 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test1 c WHERE c.go = b.go);
```